# Loomis and Sternberg Problem 1.36

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, problem-solving

[image]

Let $\mathbb{W} = \{W_i\}_{i \in I} $ be an indexed set containing every subspace of $V$ that includes $A$. Since the intersection of subspaces is a subspace, $\mathbb{W} = \bigcap_{i \in I} W_i$ is a subspace. $A \subseteq \mathbb{W}$ so $L(A) \subseteq \mathbb{W}$. How do I prove $\mathbb{W} \subseteq L(A)$?

Thanks

Comment: $L(A)$ is itself one of the spaces $W_i$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy That’s brilliant! Thanks a lot